# A pandas to_tde function for Tableau Data Extracts?

Tags: python, pandas, tableau-api

I know that Tableau is fairly popular so I cannot be the only person who is using the Python TDE API to get data into the compressed Tableau format. [Documentation](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_working_with_extracts.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____7)

1) This API is only Python 2.7 and it is literally the only reason why I need 2.7 installed

2) I use pandas to process and clean raw data and prepare it for Tableau, but then I need to read an intermediate .csv in a 2.7 environment with csv reader and do row based operations (so pandas creates a .csv, then I open that with Python 2.7 and do my TDE stuff)

Here is an example code that I have. The first portion is just creating an empty .tde file and defining the data type per column which can be done separately. The last chunk is what I wish I could do in pandas with a to_tde method. It is inserting each row of data into the tde file along with the data type.

```
#this doesnt need to be included, it is creating the empty tde table
    ExtractAPI.initialize()
    start_time = time.clock()

    if os.path.isfile(extract_file):
        print('Deleting file', extract_file)
        os.remove(extract_file)

    try:
        tde_file = Extract(extract_file)
    except:
        os.remove(extract_file)
        tde_file = Extract(extract_file)

    csv = csv.reader(open(data_location + csv_filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    print('Done reading .csv')

    #this stuff doesn't really matter, this is just creating the empty tde file

    dates = [list of column names]
    strings = [list of column names]
    doubles = [list of column names]
    ints = [list of column names]

    def create_column(column, dtype):
        tabledef.addColumn(column, dtype)

    if tde_file.hasTable('Extract'):
        print('Error')
        table = tde_file.openTable('Extract')
        tabledef = table.getTableDefinition()
    else:
        tabledef = TableDefinition()
        for column in dates:
            create_column(column, Type.DATE)
        for column in strings:
            create_column(column, Type.CHAR_STRING)
        for column in doubles:
            create_column(column, Type.DOUBLE)
        for column in ints:
            create_column(column, Type.INTEGER)

    table = tde_file.addTable('Extract', tabledef)     
    print('Done')

#this is the part that I wish I could do in pandas with a to_tde function. it is inserting each row one at a time based on the datatype which was defined    

    newrow = Row(tabledef)
    next(csv)

    for line in csv:
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(line[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        newrow.setDate(0, date.year, date.month, date.day)
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(line[1], "%Y-%m-%d")
        newrow.setDate(1, date.year, date.month, date.day)
        date = dt.datetime.strptime(line[2], "%Y-%m-%d")
        newrow.setDate(2, date.year, date.month, date.day)    

        newrow.setCharString(3, str(line[3]))
        newrow.setCharString(4, str(line[4]))
        newrow.setCharString(5, str(line[5]))
        newrow.setCharString(6, str(line[6]))
        newrow.setCharString(7, str(line[7]))
        newrow.setCharString(8, str(line[8]))
        newrow.setCharString(9, str(line[9]))
        newrow.setCharString(10, str(line[10]))

        newrow.setDouble(11, float(line[11]))
        newrow.setDouble(12, float(line[12]))
        newrow.setDouble(13, float(line[13]))
        newrow.setDouble(14, float(line[14]))
        newrow.setDouble(15, float(line[15]))

        newrow.setInteger(16, int(line[16]))
        newrow.setInteger(17, int(line[17]))
        newrow.setInteger(18, int(line[18]))
        newrow.setInteger(19, int(line[19]))
        newrow.setInteger(20, int(line[20]))
        table.insert(newrow)

    tde_file.close()
    ExtractAPI.cleanup()
    print('Extract created in {} seconds'.format(time.clock() - start_time))
```

Is this something which is being worked on by anyone? Does it seem like it would be easy to do (even if not directly added to the main pandas library)?

Comment: I would love this feature! I have not seen anything like it in pandas. You might find the workarounds described in this conversation interesting/useful: https://community.tableau.com/thread/157193

Answer (score 2):

There are various open source repo's:

## TableauSDKPy3

It's a python library that can write to tde or hyper from Pandas DataFrame or pyodbc cursor. It's shipped with Tableau API, you don't need to install them as a preparation

https://github.com/JunjieW/TableauSDKPy3

## pandleau#

It's a python module that can write Pandas DataFrame to tde and hyper. However, you need to install Tableau API locally first:

https://github.com/bwiley1/pandleau

Comment: I would also add pantab to the list for Hyper extracts - it's implemented mostly in C so it has a huge focus on performance and scalability that other libraries or hand-written code might not offer https://pantab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score -4):

I stumbled upon your question searching for a solution myself. But, found another link. Maybe the following link could be of help: https://www.doingdata.org/blog/how-to-create-a-tableau-data-extract-using-python